# How to call $get from Vue.extend?

Tags: vue.js

Examples do not show how to call such function from Vue.extend. Now I am getting error:
`ReferenceError: $get is not defined`

```
var guestContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `

        <p>Guest content</p>
      <div v-for="question in questions">
       <template v-if="question.isEnabled">
          <h3 v-if="question.isEnabled">{{question.question}}</h3>

          <!-- First Level -->
            <div v-for="firstLevelAnswer in question.answers">                
              <label v-if="!question.isRadioButton"><span class="firstLevelAnswer"><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" v-on:onclick="setIsSelectedTrue()"/>{{firstLevelAnswer.answer}}</span></label>
              <label v-if="question.isRadioButton"><span class="firstLevelAnswer"><input type="radio" class="big-checkbox" name="myvalue"/>{{firstLevelAnswer.answer}}</span></label>
              <span v-if="firstLevelAnswer.isTextInput"><input type="text"/></span>
                   |  firstLevelAnswer.isSelected: {{firstLevelAnswer.isSelected}}  

            </div>
         </template>
      </div>  

    </li>

          `,
        data: function ()  {
          return {
             questions: []
          }

          },
          ready() 
          { 
            this.getQuestionsContent(),
            this.foo()
          },
          methods: 
          {

             getQuestionsContent()
             {
                this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/questions.json').then(function(response)
                {
                  this.questions = response.data;

                }); 

              },
              foo()
              {
                console.log($get('questions.question')); //HERE IS PROBLEM
              }

          }

        }
        );
```

Also can I check of value `firstLevelAnswer.isSelected` from foo? How can I reach it? It's generated in `for` loop and do not like that it can exists here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$get is an instance method of Vue components, so you have to call it with `this.$get`:

```js
foo()
  {
    console.log(this.$get('questions.question'));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's work, but what about the second part of question about access to elements in that are placed in `v-for` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your second question.

You can access the questions through `this.questions` in the `foo()` method, and loop through them from there, to access the answers and their "isSelected" properties.